Spline swift does not show anything
I follow Spline docs here: https://docs.spline.design/doc/-/docFKClkdmir#download-xcode-demo then downloaded source code demo and tried to run on XCode, but 3D avatar did now show up.
There are no error on XCode console.
import SwiftUI
import SplineRuntime

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(itemsData.items) { item in
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                                .foregroundColor(item.color)

                            // Using SplineView with URL
                            if let url = URL(string: item.url) {
                                SplineView(sceneFileURL: url)
                                    .frame(width: 470, height: 470)
                                    .cornerRadius(300)
                                    .scrollTransition { content, phase in
                                        content
                                            .scaleEffect(phase.isIdentity ? 1 : 0.75)
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 1, spacing: 0)
                        .scrollTransition { content, phase in
                            content
                                .opacity(phase.isIdentity ? 1 : 0.5)
                                .scaleEffect(phase.isIdentity ? 1 : 0.75)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 200)
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .contentMargins(64, for: .scrollContent)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)

            // Other UI components remain unchanged
            Text("Pick your avatar")
                .font(.system(size: 24))
                .padding()
                .padding()
            Button("I like it!") {}
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 198, height: 70)
                .background(
                    Color(red: 1, green: 0.36, blue: 0.36)
                        .cornerRadius(40)
                        .shadow(color: Color.red.opacity(0.4), radius: 10, y: 12)
                )
        }
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let color: Color
    let url: String
}

struct itemsData {
    static var items = [
        //To duplicate and remix the Spline scene go to -> https://app.spline.design/file/a2770bba-eb91-4dce-9cec-44857322d7ad
        Item(color: Color(red: 1, green: 0.36, blue: 0.36), url: "https://build.spline.design/apai3cgJoCAFm2n0Pp7C/scene.splineswift"),
        //To duplicate and remix the Spline scene go to -> https://app.spline.design/file/5f77c44e-411e-4420-93ac-438fe058c4ae
        Item(color: .teal, url: "https://build.spline.design/Et5hpzdGRTjv3AN3uCIL/scene.splineswift"),
        //To duplicate and remix the Spline scene go to -> https://app.spline.design/file/30f38922-2b3f-488e-bc78-14dd25fd2ba1
        Item(color: .yellow, url: "https://build.spline.design/jTcGoCgzb7UnfLMJd2cP/scene.splineswift")
    ]
}


Any help!

I found the reason. My iPhoneX have A11 chipset. But minimum requirement is A13.
